# Java read a text file without quote marks

Tags: java, text-files, read-text

Text file is like

`"Name","Salary",
"Bernard,"200000.00"`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();
String[] splitLine = line.toString().split(",");
for (String splitValue: splitLine) { 
    System.out.println(""+splitValue);
}
```

I want to display

`Name     Salary
Bernard  200000.00`

Comment: you can use `regex` for this. `str.replaceAll("\"", "");` If you need to remove commas too, just replace them with a space.

Comment: If it is a CSV file you are parsing, and from the looks of it it is, a library such as [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) might take a lot of work out of your hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Regex` method for this would be to use

```
str.replaceAll("\",\"", " ");
```

to replace each `","` with a space.

Comment: For using regex, I think replaceAll method needs to be used. Otherwise the best answer, avoids unnecessary split call

Comment: Yeah, replaceall would be fine. That's the example I used in my comment. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Something like splitValue.replace("\"", "")

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

You will also want to add a space instead of empty string here (not sure if it's a typo):

`System.out.println(""+splitValue);`